# BitBucket Rest API, change repository settings

Tags: python, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

So I have this repo: `https://bitbucket.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/`
this URL outputs alot of information about the repository

[image: repo]

I then tried to create a Python script which featch this URL information:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.get('https://bitbucket.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/GGT/repos/GRP1/', headers=headers, auth=('USERNAME', 'TOKEN'))
print(response.text)
```

This prints out the same JSON stuff, as shown in the picture.

Now I know I have a connection to the repository.
I then want to add a Webhook to this repo, but I cant seem to find out how to do this.

I tried to do something like this, but that doesn't work.

```py
json_data = {
    'title': 'BitBucket_Webhook',
    'url': 'http://uua231z:5000/bitbucket',
    'enabled': 'true',
}

response = requests.put('https://bitbucket.com/rest/webhook/1.0/projects/GGT/repos/GRP1/configurations', headers=headers, json=json_data, auth=('USERNAME', 'TOKEN'))
print(response)
```

How can I add a webhook to a repository, can't seem to find that much on the internet on how this could be possible?

**I tried this from the comments**

```py
headers = {
    # Already added when you pass json= but not when you pass data=
    # 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

json_data = {
    'title': 'BitBucket_Webhook2',
    'url': 'http://test123:5000/bitbucket',
    'enabled': 'true',
}

# Found here: https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/4.1.0/bitbucket-rest.html
response = requests.put('https://bitbucket.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/GGT/repos/grp1/webhooks', headers=headers, json=json_data, auth=('USERNAME', 'TOKEN'))
print(response)
```

But I get `<Response [405]>`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the official Atlassian documentation for the API. There is this HTTP (POST) [/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/webhooks](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.14.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm46783598031088) that might solve your needs.

Comment: I tried but I get the respone `<Response [405]>` which is `Method not allowed`. My account is admin on the website, and manually I can create these Webhooks. I posted the code for you to look at, if you want.

Comment: Hi, in your edited question i see you are using `requests.put`. In the docs, the method to invoke is a POST. Try `requests.post´ and see if it works now

Comment: If I just write `requests.post` I get response `<Response [400]>` which is `Bad Request`, but you are right, I should probably use the `post` and not `put`